# ZigBee Arduino, Incorrect parsed datas

Tags: c++, c, parsing, arduino, zigbee

I've got some trouble to make communication between 2 arduinos Uno to work.

Arduino1<>ZigBee >---------- < ZigBee <  > Arduino2

I'm currently trying to make them understand each other. The message is currently going well between the 1st Arduino to his Zigbee then to the Second Zigbee.

Arduino1<>ZigBee>----------< ZigBee--X-- Arduino2

The problem is: When I try to parse, on Arduino2 the payload of the incoming packet from the Arduino1, the messages are differents.

Since I'm using ZigBee API2, there's a CRC on the message while travelling between ZigBees so (after some investigations) I'm sure that the packet is correct where arriving on the ZigBee2 (if not, packet is dropped).

So the main event now:

```
memmove(received,xbee_Rx.getData(),24);
```

When I receive the packet

```
xbee.readPacket();
if (xbee.getResponse().isAvailable())
{
  if (xbee.getResponse().getApiId() == ZB_RX_RESPONSE)
    {
        xbee.getResponse().getZBRxResponse(xbee_Rx);
        memmove(received,xbee_Rx.getData(),24);
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {       
          Serial.print(received[i],HEX);
        }
    }
}
```

While I send this " 4144000000000000446B3AB4083E8484258 " in HEX on Arduino1

I received this " 414400000000000008C201862419B5 " in HEX on Arduino2

It's an example, datas are always wrong (apart maybe from the two first bytes). The result is kinda random and unusable for me.

I also tried to parse with

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    received[i] = xbee_Rx.getData()[i];
    Serial.print(received[i],HEX);
  }
```

but the result was kinda the same.

So my question is: Am I doing the parsing wrong? Is there a problem with the **getData()** function?

Thank you :-)

EDIT:
after some research, i've found that if i do

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(xbee_Rx.getData()); i++) {  
    Serial.print(xbee_Rx.getData()[i],HEX);
  }
        Serial.println();
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(received); i++) {     
    Serial.print(received[i],HEX);
  }
```

datas are not the same.

414400000000000008C201885358C80
414400000000000008C201862419E6

instead of
4144000000000000441A6E9B407DDD494258

So, I guess while I'm reading the data is changing and that's maybe why it f**k up datas. So, is there any way to "freeze" the Datas before I read them?

Comment: how do you send the data?

Comment: With xbee.send(TXRequest); on Arduino1 (it uses the same Library aka Xbee-Arduino); When I log packets with XCTU, the datas are correct so the problem is clearly the parsing on Arduino2

Comment: You are doing it wrong, there must be only *one* call to getResponse().  You have multiple calls now, so, yes, the data will be changing.  You need to write `XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();` and then use *response* in your parsing code.

Comment: @HansPassant, it looks like he's using `xbee.getResponse()` correctly, judging from the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/wiki/DevelopersGuide).

Comment: @HansPassant I tried but technically, I'm not supposed to use "XBeeResponse" according to the Library Documentation. And xbee.getResponse() should only change after another xbee.readPacket() has been done. So, "It shouldn't" change and since Arduino is single thread, nothing should change it. That's why i'm kinda lost here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going on:
I'm using NewSoftSerial (because one Serial is clearly not enough) and it seems to f**ck up timers (long timeout) and I was actually using either TimerOne library or the "Thread.h" library to kinda allow me to use interrupt.

Well, the whole thing was clearly messed up by the timeout on NSS so beware if you use them together in the future. I had to switch from TimerOne to Thread.h (which wasn't real threads of course), allowing me to avoid problems.

I also found that normal Serial, the one bundled with the Arduino, was playing bad stuff aswell with the timer things.

So thank you for trying to help me, but it wasn't really where I thought the problem was.

Venix